# Get position of click relative to closest relative parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to render a small div inside of a larger div at the point where the user clicks. I can do this by getting the `offsetX` and `offsetY` from the `event`. This works fine, until there are child divs inside the larger div. `onclick` event listeners for the outermost div fire off, but the `event` properties are then relative to the child clicked on instead of the parent.

I made a small example here

https://codepen.io/markgeeromano311/pen/rPppRV

You can see it works fine when clicking on the left child, since its x and y are at the same point as the parent. But when you click the right child, it clearly breaks.

The parent has to stay a flexbox, and if I can, I'd like to avoid putting listeners on each child as a fix.

Thank you!

```js
document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('click', renderCM)

function renderCM(e) {
  const cm = document.getElementById('contextmenu')
  console.log(e)
  cm.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px'
  cm.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px'
  cm.style.display = 'block'
}
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#contextmenu {
  display: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#outermost {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="outermost">
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="contextmenu"></div>
    <div onclick=alert class="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Jimmy please place the code here, to ensure that questions and answers are whole.

Comment: Also, use mouse move to track location of mouse. Then get element at point to determine if you are in the bounds of the desired element.

Comment: You should use layerX and layerY it will provide x and y relative to closest positioned element. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217333/difference-between-layerx-and-offsetx-in-javascript) might help.

Comment: I built a small library that can do these things. It desperately needs a rewrite though: https://github.com/brainlessdeveloper/spot.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, adding individual event listeners to the children is unnecessary. You can get the relative offset of the child `div` with `e.target.offsetLeft` and `e.target.offsetTop`, then adding that to `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY` it should give you the correct location for the `cm` regardless of the number of `divs`:

```js
document.getElementById('outer').addEventListener('click', renderCM)

function renderCM(e) {
 const cm = document.getElementById('contextmenu')
 cm.style.left = e.target.offsetLeft + e.offsetX + 'px'
 cm.style.top = e.target.offsetTop + e.offsetY + 'px'
 cm.style.display = 'block' 
}
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#contextmenu {
  display: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#outermost {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="contextmenu"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** A much better solution:

```
function renderCM(e) {
    const cm = document.getElementById('contextmenu')
    cm.style.left = e.layerX + 'px'
    cm.style.top = e.layerY + 'px'
    cm.style.display = 'block'  
}
```

credit to @Alok Singh for pointing out `layerX` and `layerY`

Comment: This works for this example. But lets assume there are a dozen or so children. Then this gets a bit cumbersome to do.

Comment: I have edited my answer, my solution no longer requires `ids` and works with any amount of `divs` as long as they have the same parent.